# How can I change the text color in gnome top bar?

Tags: gnome, configuration, gnome-shell, color-management, appearance

[image: I want to change the text color of notification from green to black]

I want to change the text color of notification from green to black for example.
I'm using [Xenlism Minimalism](https://github.com/xenlism/minimalism), that is the great shell for me, but the only issue is that the text color is light green really hard to see.
How can I change this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- go to your theme, usually installed in `/usr/share/themes/<your_theme_folder>/gnome-shell`
- find `.message-title` and `.message-content` selector
- add color or do whatever you want to it

Comment: There's no such file as `gnome-shell` in Ubuntu 18.04 :(

Comment: @RishabhAgrahari The file to look for is gnome-shell.css in the quoted folder /usr/share/themes/<your_theme_folder>/gnome-shell

Comment: That file only exists Yaru theme and not any others in Ubuntu 20